# Why does capturing urls with proper protocols fail?

Tags: python, regex

I started writing a regex to try to capture as many urls as possible. However, for some reason, I cannot make it work.

**Regex:**

```
^(https?|ftps?|mailto|gopher|telnet|www\.)\:.+?\/(?=\s)
```

**Demo:** [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/FRzGBJ/1)

Any help is appreciated. Thx in advance.

Comment: Why do you have `(?=\s)` in your pattern? Remove it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, because else it will just capture whatever comes after the actual URL string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, this one works, but not as expected: https://regex101.com/r/FRzGBJ/4

Comment: `^(?:(?:https?|ftps?|mailto|gopher|telnet):\/\/|www\.)\S+` is better.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, thx. But, it fails to capture: "mailto", see: https://regex101.com/r/FRzGBJ/5

Comment: Ok, try `^(?:(?:https?|ftps?|gopher|telnet):\/\/|www\.|mailto:)\S+`, see https://regex101.com/r/FRzGBJ/8

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I am trying this:  ^(?:(?:https?|ftps?|mailto|gopher|telnet|file):(?=\/\/)|www\.)\S+  ---- however, it fails to capture the "mailto"

Comment: Sure, `mailto` is not followed with `://`. Use `^(?:(?:https?|ftps?|gopher|telnet):\/\/|www\.|mailto:)\S+`

Comment: I am trying to make (?=\/) if followed by

Comment: But it makes no difference. Why do you want to make it a lookahead? Even in that case, keep the alternations as I showed, `^(?:(?:https?|ftps?|gopher|telnet)(?=:\/\/)|www\.|mailto:)\S+`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/FRzGBJ/9).

Comment: > Why do you want to make it a lookahead?, maybe efficiency? Maybe I am newbie"

Comment: Extra check means extra overhead - no performance gain. Does my regex work as expected? Is it the solution?

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?:(?:https?|ftps?|gopher|telnet):\/\/|www\.|mailto:)\S+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FRzGBJ/9) and [its graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(%3F%3A(%3F%3Ahttps%3F%7Cftps%3F%7Cgopher%7Ctelnet)%3A%5C%2F%5C%2F%7Cwww%5C.%7Cmailto%3A)%5CS%2B):

[image]

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:(?:https?|ftps?|gopher|telnet):\/\/|www\.|mailto:)` - any of

  - `(?:https?|ftps?|gopher|telnet):\/\/` - `http`, `https`, `ftp`, `ftps`, `gopher` or `telnet` and then `://` substring
  - `|` - or
  - `www\.` - `www.` substring
  - `|` - or
  - `mailto:` - `mailto:` substring
- `\S+` - 1 or more non-whitespace chars.

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern `\/(?=\s)` requires the URL to end in a slash. You can check this by adding a slash to the end of any of the URLs in your test snippet.

There's no real reason to do that - you can just remove the `\/` and allow the URL to end on any character followed by a whitespace.

**However**, in addition to this you should be aware that the whitespace thing isn't very robust. If a URL occurs in text, it may be followed by punctuation or parentheses, which are technically valid URL characters and which your filter (minus the `\/`) will include, even though they are likely not part of it.

There's obviously some ambiguity in these cases, but it might be a better heuristic to exclude any punctuation characters at the end of the URL.

(If you want to be *really* sophisticated about it, you can do what GitHub's markdown parser does, and include closing parentheses at the end *if and only if* they match with opening parentheses inside the URL. This helps recognize links in contexts like like `(See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Something_(disambiguation))`. But this isn't feasible with only regex, and requires some extra processing.)